# Переадресация после работы скрипта

Tags: php

есть у меня файл **index.php** , где я ввожу необходимые данные и после нажатия на сабмит они обрабатываются скриптом **second.php** , можно после обработки вот так делать :
**second.php**

```
<?php
...
...
...обработка
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

или это неправильно??тогда как правильно сделать переадресацию после выполнения скрипта на нужный файл?

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, так. Только exit добавьте

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

Comment: спасибки Вам

Comment: а лучше  - die();

Я так всегда делаю. Слово красивое просто. И никогда не подведет.

Comment: die - это синоним exit

Comment: @Fike, я не думаю, чтобы разработчики php так пошутили. Вообще-то exit - это выход, а die - это **функция** ))))

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.die.php

Comment: @Fike, да, они пошутили. Согласен с вами. Почитал. Равнозначные инструкции, однако ))), но  die - это все-таки die, а не просто exit )))